# AEM classic UI how to and good readings

Tags: aem

I am working on AEM 6.2 and I am interested is there any good blogs, tutorials or anything else you can recommend to read about it.
In more detail, I was looking something more detailed about using listeners in the dialog files, and cant find anything that would be a good read about it.
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

**1) ClassicUI**
If you looking specifically for the Classic UI, you'll need to focus on tutorials around CQ tutorials to give you the 101.

**2) General Reading**
Here are some links, that could get you started:
**Quick Video**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jQb5y6wupA
**101s**
http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/aem-cq5-tutorial/
http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__zjpb-hello_communitymemb.html
**AEM Learning from Tech Up**
https://8bitplatoon.blogspot.co.za/2016_01_01_archive.html

**Adobe's Master Reference**
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy.html#What%20is%20AEM?
I find this super useful and well structured.

Best of luck.. and enjoy the journey.